# how to select class=" * " in jQuery .html()

Tags: jquery, html, regex, highlight

How can I select class(or any other) string="*" in code returned from .html() ?

If we had element's html written to another element (as text). (like snippet with preview)

```html
<div class="myClass">1</div>
<div class="myElem">2</div>
<div class="myBox">3</div>
```

These divs are not objects, but text, so:

```
&lt;div class="myClass"&gt; 1 &lt;/div&gt;
&lt;div class="myElem"&gt; 2 &lt;/div&gt;
&lt;div class="myBox"&gt; 3 &lt;/div&gt;
```

How can I select string "class" and its value/content and replace with `<strong>` + string + `</strong>` for example to highlight something in this html code (which is actually a text).

```html
class="myClass"
class="myElem"
class="myBox"
```

Something similiar to `class=" * "` ...

So I will be able to select and replace:

```
var string = "class=*"
var regex = new RegExp(string, 'gi');
var text = $("#htmlCode").html().replace(regex, '<span class="strong">' + string + '</span>');
$("#htmlCode").html(text);
```

Comment: Something like: `$("div").html(function() { return "<strong>" + this.getAttribute("class") + "</strong>"; })` ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L3491c9r/)) ?

Comment: No, the divs are text not objects. Maybe it would be more clear with &lt; and &gt;... (https://jsfiddle.net/L3491c9r/1/)

Answer (score 0):

This would be what you're looking for with your code:

```js
$(function(){
  var $context = $("#context");
  var regex = /(<div[\s]*class=\"[^\"]*\">)([^<]*)(<\/div>)/gmi;
  $context.html($context.html().replace(regex, '$1<strong>$2</strong>$3'));
});
```

```css
strong{
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="context">
  <div class="myClass">1</div>
</div>
```

But honestly, using `.html()` will

1. destroy events
2. trigger DOM regeneration

And since you've mentioned:

> for example to highlight

I would recommend to use [mark.js](https://markjs.io/) instead of implementing the highlighting component this way.

Comment: This code unfortunately does not work for me and according to your snippet this is not what I looking for.
Once again, the <div class="myClass">1</div> is not a DOM object / element it's text in element <p> for example so :
<p><div class="myClass">1</div></p> so less than "<" is actually "&lt;" Where I wish to highlight class="myClass" not the 1 digit.